# How to get value from javascript in asp.net page based on masterpage which can have only one asp.net form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I want to create a quick simulation of One Time Password. Problem is I am in a masterpage child page and I can only have one asp.net form in one contentplaceholder, the other contains a javascript code that generates the random code.

How can I pass this code to asp.net so that when user clicks on validate, I can compare the code he enters with the random code generated by javascript (ajax maybe but I can't see how ?)

If I could have 2 asp.net forms it wouldn't be a problem.

Update: I have modified source code below to include solution suggested by Andrei.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Username: <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" /></br>
        OTP: <asp:TextBox ID="txtOTP" runat="server" /></br>
        <asp:TextBox ID="OtpHiddenField" runat="server" /></br>
        <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" onclick="btnValidate_Click" Text="Validate" /></br>
</form>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
<h2>Fake OTP Simulation</h2>
Enter "John"
</br>
Enter OTP 
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var pass = String(getRandomInt(0, 9)) + String(getRandomInt(0, 9)) + String(getRandomInt(0, 9)) + String(getRandomInt(0, 9));
    document.write(pass);
    document.getElementById('<%= OtpHiddenField.ClientID %>').value = pass;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert generated value into the hidden field that will be posted with the form.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Username: <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" /><br/>
        OTP: <asp:TextBox ID="txtOTP" runat="server" /><br/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" onclick="btnValidate_Click" Text="Validate" /><br/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="OtpHiddenField" runat="server" />
</form>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<h2>Fake OTP Simulation</h2>
Enter "John"
<br/>
Enter OTP 
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    var pass = String(getRandomInt(0, 9)) + String(getRandomInt(0, 9)) + String(getRandomInt(0, 9)) + String(getRandomInt(0, 9));
    document.write(pass);
    document.getElementById('<%= OtpHiddenField.ClientID %>').value = pass;
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

And I hope you are aware that this approach is very, very vulnerable.

Comment: Clever idea. Nonetheless when I test OtpHiddenField.Value in Page_Load it's always empty string (""). Why ?

Comment: For vulnerability it's ok because it's just for protyping functionally :)

Comment: @user310291, worked for me, just tried it locally. Are there any javascript errors on the page? Maybe generated password was not inserted in the field.

Comment: Your code works on dom side, I get otp value from hidden side. But when I click on validate, on codebind side (see my code update above) OtpHiddenField.Value gives empty string. It's illogical I know but did you actually test codebehind ?

Comment: @user310291, yes I did tested the code behind as well, but with little difference. ASP.NET allows only one form on the page, and usually it is generated in the Master page already. So I commented out the `form` tag in your code. I have no idea how ASP.NET would behave with nested form, although I do know that it is not supposed to handle this scenario. Actually I should have pointed it out in the answer, sorry for that.

Comment: I changed from Hidden field to normal textBox and it shows blank ie document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_OtpHiddenField').value doesn't seem to work. Is it because my ContentPlaceHolder1_OtpHiddenField is AFTER the script ?

Comment: That's it: I moved document.getElementById to another content zone at the very end and now it works perfect thanks a lot I marked as right answer :)

Comment: @user310291, aha, seems that the issue was in the order of loading. When the script was executed DOM model was not loaded completely, and the search on it did not worked correctly. What you've done was one possible solution, another way could be executing all the script in `window.onload` handler.

Comment: Can you check if the value is actually set on client side using debugger.

Comment: @Ravia, both user310291 and me checked and confirmed that script was working on the client side.